# EADDRINUSE, Address already in use on each port I tried (Express Node.js) also after a complete reinstallation from bios

Tags: node.js, express, port

I'm on windows. I was following this getting started https://expressjs.com/it/starter/hello-world.html
It worked but at some point I unistalled a software on my pc that was running on port 3000 and now, also if I restart my pc, every time I execute that code I get EADDRINUSE error also if I change the port number to something arbitrary like 3039 or 4012. I used netstat but I didn't find any process at 127.0.0.1 (not 127.0.0.0 as I thought). I'm using git bash (mingw64) to execute node and scripts

Here what netstat says:
[image: netstat]

Update: I tried to reinstall the old program that was running on 127.0.0.1:3000 and it worked because it showed its interface.
Then, unistalled this program and unistalled node.js.
Then, reinstalled node.js and again, executing my server it says address in use.
I also tried to create a new project in a different directory making npm init and then npm install express and again, executing that simple server, I got the same result.
If I go to 127.0.0.1:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3001 (this last one is the port I used in this new project for the express getStarted server) I got connection refused and this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
I don't know what to do now...

New update:
I looked in windows defender firewall app allowed to comunicate and I tried disabling and enabling private/public, noone, both with no luck...
[image]

new new update: I also refreshed my pc like explained here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-refresh-reset-or-restore-your-pc-51391d9a-eb0a-84a7-69e4-c2c1fbceb8dd and this problem is here yet.
I will try now to reset deleting all files following the other guide at the same link.

New new new update: I made a complete new installation from bios using an external pendrive. I have no idea on how to resolve now... I’m desperate

Comment: Are u using 127.0.0.0 as the IP? If yes change that to 127.0.0.1

Comment: No, I made a mistake, as shown in the picture

Comment: The Windows Defender Firewall or some antivirus might be blocking it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to allow node js in the firewall